# PowerShell $ + $

Tags: powershell

I thought I would get fancy and try to learn how to add variables in PS but I'm not able to add these commands together it would seem or am I just missing something obvious? Had ran it in the 7.1.4 terminal as Admin as well as VS-Code.

$UDS = Get-PSDrive | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'C'} | Select Used

$FDS = Get-PSDrive | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'C'} | Select Free

$DriveTotal = $UDS + $FDS

$DriveTotal

Comment: Just use the cmdlet once and reference it's properties.

Comment: Im not sure im fallowing, can you show an example please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are trying to add two `PSCustomObject` items to each other ... and that object type *does not have an addition method*. [*grin*]

what you *want* to add is the value in the single property of each object. this ...

```
$FDS.Free + $UDS.Used
```

... will give you what you want.

however, i would use something like ...

```
$CDriveInfo = Get-PSDrive -Name 'c'
$TotalSize_CDrive = $CDriveInfo.Free + $CDriveInfo.Used

$TotalSize_CDrive
```

... OR use `Get-Volume` OR a CIM query since those have the drive capacity directly available.

Comment: Ah, thanks! As I am still new what should I investigate as I would of never of thought to make my variables .Free and .Used?

Comment: @XXLMamdalorian, It's called *dot notation*, when you're referencing an objects properties using the (`.`) *operator*. So he basically dot referenced the properties to add.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I see, i'll look into that. Thanks!

Comment: @XXLMandalorian - you are most welcome! [*grin*] ///// take a look at what you get when you send an object/variable to `Get-Member`. for instance, run your code and then do `$FDS | Get-Member` to see what is in the object that the $Var refers to.